# Is there a particular reason why resignFirstResponder() is not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, search, uisearchbar

I'm trying to implement a method in Xcode called "shouldHideSearchKeyboard" which simply hides the keyboard when the return key is pressed. The problem is, not only is resignFirstResponder() not being called, shouldHideSearchKeyboard isn't even being called, indicating that something is seriously wrong. I'm confused by this since (1) I've tried every solution regarding this issue proposed on the website and (2) I implemented the exact same function except with textfields with no issue.
Thank you!

I have double checked to make sure UISearchBarDelegate has been added to my SearchTab class, included a UISearchBar as a parameter in the method, made an IB outlet connecting the search bar to my code, and setting the delegate of the outlet equal to self. Nonetheless, shouldHideSearchkeyboard is never called.

```
@IBOutlet weak var IB_SearchBar: UISearchBar!
class SearchTab: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
   override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.IB_SearchBar.delegate = self
}

func hideSearchBarKeyboard(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool
    {
// Neither resignation nor print statement gets called
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        print("Search bar entry")
return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is talking about `shouldHideSearchKeyboard`. Your code has a method named `hideSearchBarKeyboard`. But what should call either of these methods that you have invented? There is no such delegate method of UISearchBar` with either method.

Comment: @ingconti Lmao thank you, it didn't occur to me that the functions I made were not listed under the Apple Documentation. After reading it and using searchBarButtonClicked(UISearchBar), it works.

Answer (score 0):

pls use std apple notification. Add a delegate and use Apple delegate functions:

in didLoad set delegate...

```
//MARK: UISearchBarDelegate


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) // called when text changes (including clear) {
        self.reload.....
```

}

Answer (score -1):

if `searchBar` is the only responder you could use;

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

&

`view.endEditing(true)` instead of `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`